# thick line and rectangle intersection java

Tags: java, line, intersection, rectangles

In Java We can find whether a line2D intersects a given rectangle2D using the **intersects()** method, but that is assuming the line is 1 pixel wide.
If I draw my line after setting the basicstroke to thicker than 1 pixel how can I find if that thick line intersects the rectangle or not?? Same question applies to Quadcurve2D!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
Shape strokedShape = basicStroke.createStrokedShape(Shape s)
```

Then you can do the intersection using the `strokedShape`.